# How to use will in tag questions

Tags: negation, question-tags, will-would

> Open the door, will you?
>   Open the door, won't you?

As I know the first one is the right one, but last week I came across with the second one, so I am really confused now.

Comment: I think these are just examples of [sentence inversion](http://grammar.about.com/od/il/g/inversionterm.htm) from *Will/won't you open the door?*, not [tag questions](http://www.perfect-english-grammar.com/tag-questions.html) (used to turn a ***statement** into a question*).

Comment: No, it isn't inversion, it is tag question,

Comment: You're sure of that, are you? Give us a reference, will you? (That second example sounds like "Yoda-speak" to me! :)

Comment: ok, what about " Don't close the door, will you?"

Comment: Negation doesn't make any difference - all permutations of *Do/don't open/close the door* are imperatives, not statements. But I'm only saying I *think* your examples aren't tag questions. If you can provide a reference showing they *are*, I'll shut up.

Comment: No, it is alright, I might be wrong.

Comment: Ok, if it is inversion, still I don't know which one to use

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29078/discussion-between-sanjar-igamov-and-fumblefingers).

Comment: The rule for forming tag questions starts with a statement; statements have subjects. _Open the door_ is not a statement; it can't be either true or false. It is an order, and must be obeyed or disobeyed. Orders (imperatives) can't form tag questions, because there is no statement to question. However, they can participate in indirect requests by making formal questions out of them; instead of bald _Open the door_, one says _Would/Could/Will you open the door?_, usually with _please_. This, in turn, can undergo inversion, producing _Open the door, would/could/will you?_ Not a tag question.

Comment: And so the difference between your two examples is the same as the difference between _Will you open the door?_ (a command or request) and _Won't you open the door?_ (either an invitation, or a peremptory command, depending on the tone of voice).

Comment: What is confusing you?

Answer (score 0):

This is an imperative one

In positive imperatives we can use taq questions with won't

In negative imperatives we can use taq questions with will

Like these examples

1. Stop talking , won't you?
2. Don't tell anyone , will you?

So in your example 2nd one is correct